# textfield maskRe dont type dot extjs 5 bug?

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs, extjs5

My app has a textfield which only allow numbers (no comma or dot).

The following regex on maskRe works in extjs 4 and 6, but it isn't working in extjs 5.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
  title: 'Textfield as numberfield',
  width: 300,
  bodyPadding: 10,
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'number',
    fieldLabel: 'Number',
    maskRe: /[0-9]/
  }]
});
```

Is this a bug?

Is there any work-around for it?

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/153c

Comment: `<input type="number" />` or `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" />`

Comment: How many digits are there in your number ?

Comment: seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/c449p7L2/

Comment: Thanks Tushar. I Think your suggestion is not working in my case. I edited  de fiddle.

Comment: Thanls noob. The number of digits is almost unlimited. It is a field for value in euros.

Comment: Thanks Musa. See my fiddle with extjs 5 version, and change for extjs 4 or 6

Comment: You have used `[0-9]` with no `quantifiers`. In this case it will match only **one** digit. To match unlimited digits you should use `+` or `*`. `+` stands for _one or many_ whereas `*` stands for _zero or many_.

Comment: Apparently seems to a be a bug. An alternative could be using  `stripCharsRe: /\D/` instead of `maskRe`

Comment: Thanks noob my mistake. I fix this part in fiddle with your sugestion.

Comment: Thanks leo. Your suggestion solves de issue. If you want you can put it in a answer to mark as solved

Comment: @josei: This will not work if a user presses and hold `.` key. Then, only the last dot will be erased. You need to prevent non-numeric input before.

Comment: You are right Wiktor. Any idea to solve?

Comment: For if it is not found a better solution to solve, I edited my fiddle with a "Plan B"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code:

```
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'number',
            fieldLabel: 'Number',
            maskRe: /[0-9]/
        }]
```

the `maskRe` is correctly applied in 5.1.2, but not in 5.1.1. I found [this forum thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?302298) regarding that issue. So I fear that you have to either upgrade to new Ext or backport the bugfix.

Furthermore it seems that there is confusion about what `maskRe` does.

`maskRe` is applied to the current keystroke only. If your field contains `elis` and you type an `a`, it will only check whether `maskRe` does allow `a`, but not whether it allows `elisa`. So you can define a certain set of characters that may be typed, but you can't define that a certain character may be typed at most once or that after every `a` you have to type `b`. For the reason that the keystroke always contains exactly one character, using quantifiers on the `maskRe` is useless, but not actively harmful.

For other validations there is [`regex`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-regex), which will not prevent typing, but mark the field as invalid unless the regex is met; or you have to add a `change` or `blur` event and make a check yourself (and change the value if invalid).

Note that you can easily disallow submission/processing of an invalid form, that is, a form with at least one invalid field. You don't have to remove the erroneous entry, you can let the user correct it (e.g. add a single missing digit to the IBAN instead of having to type it all over again)

I would recommend using the `change` event to check for double comma, or to change dot to comma or vice versa (depending on your required input format).